# is it possible to report mantis issue while setting its status to resolved at the same time?

Tags: mantis

More often than not I need to submit a resolved issue for record keeping purpose. But need to set the status to 'resolved' after submission, costing some more annoying mouse clicks. Is it possible to report mantis issue while setting its status to resolved at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible out of the box. If you know some PHP you could modify the source code yourself. It's not complicated because Mantis has very clean and self explanatory code.

There are some downfalls to this solution as you will not be able to update to new versions of Mantis without little extra effort from your side.

Comment: This is indeed not possible in the current version of MantisBT (1.2.14)